# Drawing in Metal using Mesh

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

I want to create the feature as mentioned below in Picture. The number tells the touch order in the screen and dot tells the position. I want to create as same effect.

We can do this using normal drawing index primitive method. But I want to know whether Is it possible to create this effect using MTKMesh ? Please suggest/give some ideas to perform this in better way ? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use a `MTKMesh` in this case. After all, if you have all of the vertex and index data, you can just place it directly in one or more `MTLBuffer` objects and use those to draw. Using MetalKit means you'll need to create all kinds of intermediate objects (a `MDLVertexDescriptor`, a `MTKMeshBufferAllocator`, one or more mesh buffers, a submesh, and an `MDLMesh`) only to turn around and iterate all of those superfluous objects to get back to the underlying Metal buffers. `MTKMesh` exists to make it easy to import 3D content from model files via Model I/O.